# Friendly links with $_GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

so I've got links like that:

```
mywebsite.com/index.php?sub=main
```

And I want to convert it to

```
mywebsite.com/strona-glowna
```

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Answer (score 0):

You need to take help of htaccess.
create a file with name .htaccess 
and paste this code there

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase /

 # skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)\strona-glowna$ index.php?sub=$1 [QSA,L]
```

if that doesn't help try replacing with this

```
RewriteRule    ^strona-glowna/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?sub=$1    [NC,L]    # Process parrots
```

Comment: try this i have made change